# Prevent macro expansion in false branch of if expression

Tags: macros, clojure, expansion

In Clojure, the branch of an `if` expression that doesn't match the condition is not evaluated, so no exception is thrown in evaluating the below expression:

```
=> (if nil (/ 1 0))
nil
```

However, macros will still be expanded before evaluating the `if`, so you can still get exceptions like so:

```
=> (if nil (proxy [nil] []))
CompilerException java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```

I'm writing a macro for which the name of an interface will sometimes be provided as an arg, in which case the macro will generate the code for a call to `proxy`. Other times, the interface arg will be `nil`, and then the macro expands to something like `(if nil (proxy [nil] [])`, so I get the above exception. An SSCE would be:

```
=> (defmacro make-listener [listener-name & methods]
     `(if ~listener-name
        (proxy [~listener-name] []
          ~@(map (fn [m] `(~m [e#])) methods))))
#'user/make-listener
=> (make-listener java.awt.event.ActionListener actionPerformed)
#<Object$ActionListener$46793e3a user.proxy$java.lang.Object$ActionListener$46793e3a@ed5b2>
=> (make-listener nil)
CompilerException java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```

How can I write the macro in a way that doesn't throw an exception when no interface arg is provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If listener-name is nil then the macro should do nothing i.e you need to check for listener-name at macro expansion (not in the code the macro emit).

```
(defmacro make-listener [listener-name & methods]
  (if listener-name
     `(proxy [~listener-name] []
       ~@(map (fn [m] `(~m [e#])) methods))))
```

Comment: Ankur, I don't understand why yours works but sauce's doesn't.. shouldn't the 'if' clause in sauce's example delay the creation of the proxy in the same way yours does?

Comment: @jk: `proxy` is a macro and it throws the null exception when it is being macro-expanded by the compiler. The null exception is compile time exception not runtime exception.